# Is each component in a composite key a non-key attribute on its own?

Tags: database-design, database-normalization, 3nf

If I have a composite primary key (for example in the table below First Name and Product Name) does this mean that First Name alone is a non-key attribute and Product Name alone in a non-key one?

```
First Name       Product Name       Manufacturer
-------------------------------------------------
  F1                P1                  M1
  F2                P2                  M2
  F3                P3                  M3
```

and does this mean that there is a non-key dependency between Manufacturer and Product Name and accordingly it's not in 3NF?

Comment: Together they make composite key. Alone they are indices and foreignkey in this table and probably primary key in their own tables.

Comment: "Between" is not clear. It doesn't imply a direction. Either write a FD or use enough words, properly, to say what you mean. Eg Manufacturer -> Product Name, or a FD from Manufacturer to Product Name, or a FD where Manufacturer determines Product Name, etc. Or in the other direction if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a composite primary key (for example in the table below First Name and Product Name) does this mean that First Name alone is a non-key attribute and Product Name alone in a non-key one?

No.

Find a correct textbook definition of 3NF & the terms it uses. A "prime" attribute is one that is a component of any CK (candidate key). So a "non-prime" attribute is one that is not a component of any CK. So each of First Name & Product Name is prime, and so not non-prime. It is sloppy to use "key" instead of "prime" or "CK".